# Add large array to c file without recompiling it

Tags: arrays, c

I use header files to store a dataset in float arrays like so:

```
//header
float MNIST_test_data_label[1000][10] = {{...},...};
```

I include these headers in my main.c and can use the arrays, but the IDE (CodeBlocks) keeps making these headers when I build. I searched for hours now, trying to find a solution to make large amounts of data in form of arrays available to my project as "resources" without the compiler constantly rebuilding them.

Does anyone know a solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: It's not clear what you want.

Comment: You want the data to be an input to your program? To change every time you **run it** (as opposed to every time you compile it)?

Comment: Including a header is functionaly the same as copying it into the source. It is just much cleaner. At best the compiler can use *pre-compiling* to use the precompiled version of an unchanged header. But if the header changes, any source file including it should be compiled again. If you do not want the recompilation, the data should not be in a header but in a data and/or config file and loaded with `fopen` and other functions from stdio.h.

Comment: The correct solution is to place that data in a .c file together with the code using it. No other file should access it. Implement private encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

Add an external declaration to the header. Add the actual definition to a dedicated C file:

```
// header
extern float MNIST_test_data_label[1000][10];
```

some C file:

```
float MNIST_test_data_label[1000][10] = {{...},...};
```

Note that a file with a single line as above should suffice.